# Creating a string from a set of elements from an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, substring, cs50

Is there a way to create a string of characters from a set of elements taken from a existing array?

Example: say I have an array of four characters

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
char abcd[] = "abcd";
string sabcd = "0";
}
```

Is there a way I can create strings with a subset of array elements, such as "ac", "cd" and so on?

Edited: added libraries for clarification.

Comment: there is no string type in c

Comment: Technically the array `abcd` is an array of *five* characters, since it will include the string terminator.

Comment: GO to this http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-find-subsets-of-string/

Comment: As for your problem, how about `char ac[3] = { abcd[0], abcd[2], '\0' };`? You can of course set up the new array `ac` using a loop and some suitable condition for which characters to include. Perhaps if you ***try*** something and have problem with your attempt, then you can come back with a new question including a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ask for help with whatever problem you have then. Also take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry, I thought this short code was enough to make my point. I am working on something bigger but is messy and does not seem right to post it here. I will read your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: The CS-50 `string` type, being a royally stupid typedef, tends to confuse professional programmers, since there is a type in C++ with the identical name `string`. But in CS-50, it is just `typedef char* string`, which is very bad practice. This is one of the main reasons why CS-50 has been dismissed as a crap tutorial by professionals. Make sure to tag CS-50 questions [tag:cs50], or better yet, ask them at https://cs50.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always index the characters you wish your substring to have.

For example:

```
char adb[4] = {abcd[0], abcd[3], abcd[1], '\0'};
```

---

Another approach is to use [`strncpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/), like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char abcd[] = "abcd";
    char bc[3] = "";
    strncpy(bc, abcd + 1, 2);
    puts(bc);
}
```

Output:

> bc

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate over the array elements like this:

```
char abcd[] = "abcd";

for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    for(int j=i; j<4; j++){
        d = abcd[i] + abcd[j];
    }
```